# Facebook Flex and feedback from Actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs-flux

I'm playing around with Facebook Flux (I'm using Fluxxor, but I don't think that's really important) with ReactJS, and so far I think they its a great way of working with the data flow in an application. However, there's one thing that I'm really struggling to get my head around. It might be that this is simply something that shouldn't be done with Flex, or that I'm missing something obvious, but hence why I'm asking...

For example, I'm building a system to log in with. Very simple - there's a Login dialog that pops up, and you enter your username and password and press the button. This calls the LoginAction.login(username, password) Action Creator, which sends the LOGIN Event to the Dispatcher and then triggers the API call to authenticate the user and make sure the credentials are correct. If we get a success back from the API then we trigger the LOGIN_SUCCESS Event to the Dispatcher, the SessionStore handles this and stores the fact that we have successfully logged in, and the details of who we are. This then triggers bits of the UI to update - for example the "Log In" button changes to a "Hello Graham" bit of text, and a "Log Out" button instead. That's all really easy and just works and makes sense.

What I'm getting stuck with is when the login fails. If I enter an invalid username/password then I want the Login Dialog to tell the user this, so that they can correct what they entered and try again. The only way that I can think of to achieve this is to send a LOGIN_FAILED Event to the Dispatcher, which is then handled by some Store that stores the last Login errors for the Dialog to display. This just feels weird though, because these errors are not application state but are instead a transitive piece of information about this one request that failed, that the user will then correct and retry.

It feels to me that this transitive state is going to be very common around API calls that might fail because of user input, and so don't belong as part of the application state but instead belong somewhere else. However, I can't work out how Flux allows this transitive state to get back to the UI to be displayed to the user...

Comment: How do you know that LOGIN_FAILED will always only be used by the dialog component?  Maybe in the future you would like to show a little red exclamation point up in the header when the login fails.  By using the dispatcher and the Flux data flow, your application stays resilient to new feature development.  Also, and more more immediately important: your React components will remain stateless, making them more consistent and easy to work with, somewhat like pure functions, in the functional programming sense.  The components just receive props, and you can keep all state in the store.

Answer (score 0):

> SessionStore handles this and stores the fact that we have successfully logged in

In your case you keep information about successful auths. Why not to keep info about unsuccessful once also at store (the same store or independent once which keeps auth state or permissions state for user)?

It's another side of your state. In this case you've just have to dispatch special event on failure (like in you case about successful login) to store(s), save new state and send changes to the UI.

Here is [the example](https://gist.github.com/ButuzGOL/707d1605f63eef55e4af#file-authstore-js-L21) which is similar to what i mean. You send a request to the server ant can dispatch an action if login fails.

Comment: The problem was that it just felt a little odd to store what is very short lived data in something that - as I understand it - is meant to be global application state. The only thing that cares about why the login failed is the dialog that the user is using, so it seems odd to store it in such a way that everything in the entire app can react to it... That might well just be my mis-understanding of flux though...

Comment: For me auth state is not a global status. It's a bunch of user's access policies. So user can get access to some features only with needed permission. By default non-authed user have some of them but after successful login he can get new once. If there will be fail he won't.
In that case we store not a one global status. We store policies and in that case unidirectional data flow of flux works very well.

Comment: The thing is though - given that flow with flux, how do you power the message that the user got their password wrong?